# Appending to the end of a page using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hoping that someone can possibly help me out with this one. I've got a php page that runs a foreach() loop that gets information from JSON and whilst this works perfectly and all I want to be able to run that same loop again and append the results to the already displayed results if that makes any sense. I could use pagination yes but in this case I'd rather append the results to the end of the current results.

Is there any way to re-run the foreach() loop? Is there any way of appending to the end of the current page in php? If so any advice or if anyone could give me a function or two that would do this would be great. I'd be open to using JQuery but again how I would do this as you can only use the `$('#div').load('page.php')` to get a php page into a div.

Thanks to anyone who can help me solve this!

Comment: It is very hard to understand what do you really want, could you post a code example?

Comment: @GeordieDave1980 Can you give your code example here? We then can improve our answer based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [PHP's output buffering functions](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) for this:

```
ob_start();
// big fat loop that uses echo or a bunch of <? and ?>
$output = ob_get_clean();

echo $output;
// results
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn Ajax. Following links from jQuery will help.
http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can not to do it with `load()` method you are using.
As
http://api.jquery.com/load/ loads the matching element with the response.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @SalmanA He wants to add some data to an existing display. For different run of his for loop different data will be generated and need to be appended to existing block. So my finding is to use ajax here.

Comment: I was refering to your answer "You need to learn AJAX" followed by a link.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a serverside script language and JS is clientside. If you want to load php you need to create an asynchronus request using ajax. You can easily do this with jQuery take a look at this page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: JQuery.load is loading information from the server - basically its a macro for Ajax requests, this is quite correct what he is doing there.
I just think he is doing it wrong, I requested a code example because his post is a little bit confusing and I quite cannot follow without a live example.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the response. It's hard to post a code example as the page is quite big in the amount of lines on it. I will try and explain it better. It's a basic php page that runs a foreach() loop to get the information at a limit of 25 posts per loop so when clicking on the "More results" button I want to re-run the loop and append the next 25 posts to the end of the already retrieved results. I am well aware of how to use AJAX and the use of the .load() function but it's where I would actually use the code to re-run the loop. The contents are being loaded from facebook graph api.

Comment: If you would like to see a running version of my page it can be seen at http://www.opengraphsearch.net running a search query and you will see how the current version works, it only brings up the next set of results without appending to the current set which for some people might be ok but this is not what I want to do, I want to cater for everyone in this case.